# Definition of Limits: x=c

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

If $0 < |x-a| < \varepsilon$, and it's possible for $x=a$, then wouldn't the equation become $0 < 0 < \varepsilon$ (which is technically impossible)?

Comment: Just use $\leq$.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax

Comment: @orion so does it automatically become a special case of ≤in that situation?

Comment: In using limits, there is not need for $x$ to actually equal $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read carefully and you will see that the definition never says $0<|x-a|<\epsilon$.

What it says (and although this may seem like a small difference, it is vitally important) is that

> **IF** $0<|x-a|<\epsilon$ **THEN** another inequality holds.

In the case $x=a$, the definition is literally saying nothing at all - the other inequality may be true or it may be false.

The reason the definition is framed in this way is precisely so that the behaviour of the function when $x=a$ is irrelevant.  A good way to understand why this is important is to consider the derivative of $f(x)$ when $x=a$, which is the limit of
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
as $x\to a$.  Clearly we must disallow the possibility $x=a$, as in this case the expression is $0/0$, which is meaningless.